# Why are events defined as delegates

Tags: events, c#-4.0, delegates, event-handling

I have started working with ASP.NET controls and there appeared a question:
"why events in ASP controls are defined as delegates, and not as methods"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because an event must point to the function that it fires somehow and in C# this mechanism is achieved by delegates.

In response to the comment:

> Then, why is such not a case with Java that uses only methods to fire
>   events?

Because Java uses the old traditional event pattern (like in C++). C# delegates are easier to use and also allow you to point to a static function rather than forcing the use of a class method.

Comment: Then, why is such not a case with Java that uses only methods to fire events?

Comment: Because Java uses the old traditional event pattern (like in c++). C# delegate is easier to use and also allows you to point to a static funtion (not only a class method like in the traditional way).

Comment: geniaz1:) No you can never request someone to vote up and consider marking your own answer as the accepted answer. You can suggest to do so however, if someone is very now to the site. In such a case, you might receive downvotes in place of upvotes.

Comment: geniaz1:) That's right but the reason for not happening as you believe might be that the question asker might want some more descriptive answer. Anyway +1 for your benefit.

Comment: oh sorry I thought you are the question asker.

Comment: The reason is: because the method of abstraction achieved with delegates is simply, impossible with methods.

Comment: Michael, why don't you add yur answer. The question doesn't seem to be answered